# Tensorflow: Could not find 'cudart64_90.dll'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, dll

Whenever I try to import Tensorflow into python 3 it throws me this error:

```
ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_90.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable.
```

I've installed CUDA 9.0 along with cuDNN 7.0. The cudart64_90.dll file exists and its directory is listed in my path environment variable. I've tried restarting both python and my computer, however, it keeps throwing this error. Are there any potential fixes I can try?[image]